# Dart / flutter login Post request

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to log in on this forum, I tried several ways (Dio, Requests ) without result.

I tested it with postman using other languages ​​and libraries (like curl, python, node) and it works like a charm.

[**EDIT**]

Ok finally got it!

once logged in, the server returns the status code 303.
and since followredirects is set to true by default, a new request was made without session cookies.

That's why I never found the session cookie in the response header.

A method similar to "history" from lib python requests would be great here.

new:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() async {

final request = new Request(
    'POST', Uri.parse('https://xenforo.com/community/login/login'))

  ..headers.addAll({"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

  ..bodyFields = {'login':'myuser',
                'password': 'mypass'}

  ..followRedirects = false;  // don't follow the damn 303 code if you're not 
                              // going to set the cookies automatically.

   final response = await request.send();
   print(response.statusCode);  // 303 redirected successfully logged in!
   print(response.headers);  // session token: xf_session=oisufhisuefhsef...

}
```

or

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {

  final client = HttpClient();
  final request = await 
  client.postUrl(Uri.parse("https://xenforo.com/community/login/login"));
  request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/x-www_form-urlencoded");
  request.followRedirects = false;
  request.write("login=myusername&password=mypass");
 final response = await request.close();

 print(response.statusCode);
 print(response.headers);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `await` or `then`, try the following code:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  http.get("https://xenforo.com/community/").then((response) {
    var ls = response.headers['set-cookie'].split(';');
    final cookie = ls[0] + '; ' + ls[5].split(',')[1];
    login(cookie);
  });
}

void login(String cookie) {
  http.post("https://xenforo.com/community/login/login/", headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': cookie
  }, body: {
    'login': 'myusernam',
    'password': 'mypass'
  }).then((response) {
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
  });
}
```

Comment: your observation makes sense, thanks. but I still haven't got it. I tried sending the cookie as a string (Cookie: '__cfuid = xxxx ...') and it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: I tried it and it does work. just make sure login and password are correct.

Comment: i need the "xf session" cookie, to make the subsequent requests and still can't get it

Comment: Doesn't *xenforo* provide an API?

Comment: I do not think so. I'm a beginner with programming, but there really must be something I'm missing. I've tested with:  Java using HttpURLConnection and with a Cookie mananger class. With python using the blessed lib requests with only 4 lines.

Comment: I don't think this is achievable using only `http` package. You might need WebView.

Answer (score 0):

ok finally got it Every time the login was successful, the request was automatically redirected without the session cookies. FollowRedirects need set to false to work properly and http.post does not have this option.

A method similar to the "history" of lib python requests would be great.